# Failed to submit iOS application to AppStore after Apple changed app id prefix

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

We followed Apple advice to change app id prefix to share keychain data between different applications. The dev builds did work, but test flight do not allow even to update application on the target device. So we decided to revert everything back to original app id prefix.

However, after reverting everything back it is impossible even to upload app to App Store. And Yes, we checked and double check keys, provisioning profiles and even create empty test project and try to upload it.

Verify in Xcode 6.4 is OK. Submission failed. Verify and submission in Xcode 6.1 both failed.

App in the developer connection - id and name is correct:
[image]

Distribution profile - correct type and bundle id:
[image]

Distribution profile - downloaded source - everything seems correct
[image]

Project settings - seems OK
[image]

Pre upload review - OK
[image]

And error during upload:
[image]

Question:
1. Does anybody have any ideas how to resolve the issue?
2. Does anybody have any GOOD technical contacts in apple? Their support quite unhelpful and actually told this is the problem on our side. However three different persons try to resolve the issue and failed.

Thanks in advance. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if this is off-topic

Comment: @RohitGupta it's not.

Comment: 1: what are that huge spaces in the plist file?? 2: why not just recreate from scratch at Apple Member center? 3: does validation works before upload to AppStore?